# Find all values such that the following matrix is normal

Tags: matrices

Find all values such that the following matrix is normal

$\begin{pmatrix}
 1/\sqrt3 & 1/\sqrt3 &  a_{13} \\
 a_{21}    &     a_{22}   &  1/3 \\
 a_{31}    &     a_{32}   &  a_{33} 
\end{pmatrix}$

I know that for a matrix to be normal AA* = A*A.

I solving this equation, but it seems impossibly complicated.  Is there a trick that I am not seeing?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: so far I tried setting the diagonals equal to each other since you get the square of the absolute values (and can treat these as there own variables) but this leaves me with three equations and 4 unknowns so it doesn't really lock anything down.  Now I will try just multiplying everything and seeing what happens

Comment: If you want to do this in an elementary way, I tried using Maple to compute $AA^\ast=A^\ast A$, and one can easily get a lot of relations between the entries.

Comment: For example, you can get that $|a_{21}|^2=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: is there a more clever way to do it?

Comment: also if you could say how you got that relation, it would be very helpful (I don't have maple)

Comment: The middle entries are $\frac{4}{9}+|a_{22}|^2=\frac{1}{3}+|a_{22}|^2+|a_{21}|^2$.

Comment: I apologize, but I realize that there is an error--- there should be an a32 instead of a 1/3